# Remove "edge ticks" on a time scale

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a time scale using D3.js.

Here is what I came up with:

[image]

The only thing that is boggling me right now is how to remove two edge ticks (circled in red). I'm drawing a graph to represent data in a week, for example from Monday 14/03/2021 to Sunday 21/03/2021. But since I don't want my Monday and Sunday to be on two edges, I added two more days to the domain (Sunday 13/03/2021 and Monday 22/03/2021) then tried to remove the dates below the two "edge ticks" but I didn't quite find a way.
I wonder if there is any better way to do it without having to add two other days to the domain. And if anybody kept the two added days, how would they remove the dates under the ticks?

Thank you.

Comment: You should post your code that generates the axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to hide the first and last g elements in your axis with css which will hide the associated ticks and labels

```
 <selector-for-your-x-axis> g:first-of-type, <selector-for-your-x-axis> g:last-of-type {
    display: none;
  }
```

The other would be to only pad 12 hours to the start and end of your domain rather than a full day so the ticks aren't generated at all